# What is C# sample code for VBScript SetLocale Function

Tags: c#, vbscript, tridion

I have got below code in VBScript.

```vb
Sub SetPageLocale()
    Dim Locale
    Dim ContextObject
    Set ContextObject=getContextObject
    Locale=getFieldValue(ContextObject.Publication.MetadataFields("Configuration").Value(1).Fields("Locale"),"")
    If Locale<>"" Then
        SetLocale(Locale)
    Else
        SetLocale("en-gb")' Move to Constants TBB
    End If

    Set ContextObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now I want to convert above code in C#. Especially I am looking for C# code for VbScript **SetLocale** function

Comment: Now i'm dealing with exactly the same code (sic!), and i bet it has more to deal with Tridion, then just a generic VBScript..

So, I would like to reitereate (now calling for Tridion gurus):
How to properly translate this snippet, given it is now a VBScript TBB, into modular templating C# TBB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you could the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class to set the locale of the current thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Comment: I think it's a better idea to use the factory method:
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

Comment: @Manu, what is this script supposed to do? In what type of application it is used? What is the `getFieldValue` function? What is the `ContextObject` type? What is the `Publication` property? What is the `MetadataFields` function? It is not a good idea to just blindly translate from one language to another. It's better to take advantage of the specific of the target language. Translating from one language to another word-by-word without taking into account the context is simply wrong.

Comment: @DiableNoir: can you elaborate why the factory would be better ?